# LNK4221: operator<< overload not exported in static library

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, linker, operator-overloading

Despite the numerous questions about similar topics, I was unable to find one that addressed my problem.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition. I have one solution containing two projects. One project is compiled as a static library, and the other is an application. The application depends upon the static library, and it compiles and runs fine.

One class (.cpp/.h pair), specifically Ref, is ignored by the linker (source listed at bottom). From my compile output, ref.cpp is compiled just before namespace.cpp. namespace.cpp indirectly includes ref.h, possibly causing the linker's first-in-last-out behavior to ignore Ref **?**

**I have an overload for operator<< in both ref.cpp and ref.h. Why does it seem to be ignored?**

```
warning LNK4221: This object file does not define any previously undefined public symbols, so it will not be used by any link operation that consumes this library  [...]Omni\Core\ref.obj  Core
```

ref.h

```
#ifndef REF_H
#define REF_H

#include <memory>
#include <ostream>

namespace Omni
{
    template<typename T>
    using Ref = std::shared_ptr<T>;
}

template<typename T>
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & s, const Omni::Ref<T> type);

#endif // REF_H
```

(I know that `using namespace Omni;` precludes the need for `Omni::`, but in debugging I like to be double-sure.)

ref.cpp

```
#include "ref.h"

using namespace Omni;

template<typename T>
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & s, const Omni::Ref<T> value)
{
    return s << *value;
}
```

Comment: How do you use this `Omni` namespace? Can you please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg This is a very good example of when that's not a rational step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah I can see what you've done. What you think is a function definition in ref.cpp is not actually a function definition (i.e. it does not generate code). It's merely a *template* function definition.

In order for this template to cause the generation of code, you have to actually reference a concrete example of the template function.

But of course nowhere in your ref.cpp does that, so when ref.cpp is compiled no concrete examples of `operator<<(std::ostream&, const Omni::Ref<T>)` have been instantiated.

When your client code calls `operator<<` on an `Omni::Ref<T>` for any `T`, it generates the call site code perfectly well because there is a template prototype, but there is no information to actually create the function's implementation - that's in ref.cpp which is not available to client code.

Solution:
Put the definition of the template function in the header file.

Comment: I noticed this directly after posting. >.< Thanks for a precise explanation of how it matters.